# Finding unique rows in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe -

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'B':[33,44,55,77,44,70]})
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe which has the row which has first occurrence in the column 'A'.

Output-

```
    A   B
0   1   33
1   2   77
2   3   70
```

For the column A there are three repeating 1s so we take the first row similarly we take the 4th row since 2 is appearing twice in the A column and so on.

Comment: Use `df = df.drop_duplicates('A')`

Comment: This question is actually a bit different than the duplicate as the indexes are RangeIndex in OP's case. Anyway, here it is `new_df = df.drop_duplicates("A").reset_index(drop=True)`